# Open cart htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I am using `opencart` and I would like to do redirect from this:

```
index.php?route=account/account to this
/account
```

and more:

```
index.php?route=account/simpleedit ->
/simpleedit
```

So from `index.php?route=account/xxx to (root)/xxx`

I am trying to do it without hard typing domain, because for now it's on `localhost`.

Comment: Ah. I've just answered but think I misunderstood what you want. The code I provided redirects from the account link to the simple edit page

Answer (score 0):

Open `/catalog/controller/account/account.php`. Find

```
public function index()
```

On the line below it put

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/simpleedit/simpleedit', '', 'SSL'));
```

and save. This will force it to redirect to that page every time

Comment: it won't help I've tryed this

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install  this module http://opencartforum.ru/files/file/554-seo-manager-dlia-ocstore-v153-i-v1541/